# In Unity, how can I cause something to happen on a specific frame of an animation?

Tags: animation, unity

I have a GameObject "enemy" with an Animator and several states, like "idle", "walk", and "attack".

I want to activate the "hitbox" when an animation "attack" starts. The problems is that the sword does not fall down immediately: it takes about 2 frames.

Is there a way to know what frame of the animation is currently being run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open the Animation Window (Window->Animation) and select your enemy **GameObject**, you can insert events for certain key frames by right clicking beneath the timeline (yellow marked area).

[image]

You can specify your own callback for this event, which has to be a function, available on your enemy. This will then be called, whenever this keyframe is being played.

Comment: Isn't this the old animation system?

Comment: @Ben This screenshot was taken from Unity 5.2 and this is the only way that I am aware of. I'm not very familiar with the whole animation system however.